# How can I access my iPad even though I don't know the passcode?

Tags: password

My iPad 2 froze up and went into recover mode, I gave t to a friend to fix and it has come bk restored but I can't get on it because there is a passcode on it.  I've tried all the obvious ones I would have used but it will not let me in to set it up. Please help me! Is there a factory '4 digit' passcode it would reset to or would it be my friends passcode?[image]

Comment: Did you try contacting your friend? How exactly is the password prompt looking like, please add the specific text displays on screen (or take a picture and add this to the question).

Comment: It is disabled at the min,

Comment: Your friend did a "restore" of your iPad?  From what image did he restore it from?